# Function composition of function of several variables

Tags: function-construction

Suppose I have the following function `g[{x_, y_}, c0_, b_] := {x^2 + c0 - b*y, x}` where `b` and `c0` are parameter values.

Suppose we fix the values of `c0` and `b`, say, `g[{x_, y_}, -5, 1.2]`. Is there a way to get the $nth$ composition of `g` with itself? So a function say `G[{x_,y_},n,-5,1.2]` which gives  `g[{x, y}, -5, 1.2] @* g[{x, y}, -5, 1.2] @* ... @* g[{x, y}, -5, 1.2]` $n$ times? I would like to then use this to find period $n$ points using `NSolve` so I think this is the form I would require.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
gcomp[n_Integer] := Composition @@ ConstantArray[g[#, -5, 1.2] &, n]
```

Which you can then use as:

```
gcomp[3][{0, 0}]
```

Or perhaps even better:

```
gcomp[n_Integer, c0_, b_] := Composition @@ ConstantArray[g[#, c0, b] &, n];
gcomp[3, -5, 1.2][{0, 0}]
```

Comment: This is wonderful thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
n=3;
g[{x_, y_}, c0_, b_] := {x^2 + c0 - b*y, x};
Nest[Function[t, g[t, -5, 1.2]], {x0, y0}, n]
```

Comment: `n = 3;
g[{x_, y_}, c0_, b_] := {x^2 + c0 - b*y, x};
Nest[g[#, -5, 1.2] &, {x0, y0}, n]`